# Need ideas for HTTPS multiple domain solution

Tags: ssl, domain-mapping, https

I'm developing a WordPress site that runs on multiple domains (not WordPress MU). The two domains are served from the same codebase and I have written a plugin that successfully switches themes based on the URL.

This site has a donation form that uses HTTPS (currently using the [WordPress HTTPS](https://github.com/Mvied/wordpress-https/blob/master/lib/WordPressHTTPS.php) plugin). However, WordPress HTTPS only has one option for the domain.

I thought that I could maybe get away with replacing this line
`$ssl_host = rtrim($this->getSetting('ssl_host'), '/') . '/';`

...with this
`$ssl_host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/';`

Unfortunately, it's not that easy. It seems to break the whole site. The site header (and consequently everything else) won't load properly.

Any ideas? Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I just needed to scrap the plugin and use the following code in my htaccess...AND switch my site/home URL to https://. But, now we're all good.

Here's what I used, in case anyone else has this issue:

```
# BEGIN HTTPS REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS REDIRECT
```